# Search box in gridview with pagination

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to do a search box with these "components": textBox, button and gridview **with pagination**. In my gridview there are name, last name and personal code. 
The idea, user write something in textbox and press button, then search persona code in the first page and if it's found then I change background row, else, continues with the second page and if it's found is show this page and change background. 
I have something, but my problem is that always compare whit personal code of first page. My code:

```
    protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string search= txtSearch.Text;

        for (int pageNumber= 0; pageNumber< MyGridView.PageCount; pageNumber++)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow gr in MyGridView.Rows)
            {
                //Cells[2] is 'personal code'
                bool found = gr.Cells[2].Text.Contains(search);
                if (found)
                {
                    //MyGridView.PageIndex = pageNumber;
                    //MyGridView.DataBind();
                    MyGridView.Rows[gr.RowIndex].Style.Add("BACKGROUND-COLOR", "#aaccee");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there something like this?

```
 gr.Page[X].Cells[Y].Text
```

Thanks

Comment: Your are breaking the loop with "break" on first search element that is why it always compare whit personal code of first page

Comment: I put the "break" for stop the loop if I found a personal code.
I have deleted the "break" and continues comparing always with personal code of the first page. However the number page is correct.

Comment: For more information, it compare with the correct row index but always for the first page, although pageNumber change value. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private bool _isStop = false;
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string search= txtSearch.Text;

    for (int i= 0; i< MyGridView.PageCount; i++)
    {
        MyGridView.PageIndex = i;
        //MyGridView populate page here (MyGridView_View(sender, e))
        for (int j=0; j< MyGridView.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            GridViewRow row = MyGridView.Rows[j];

            if (row.Cells[2].Text.Contains(search)) // cell[2] is personal code as you said.
            {
                _isStop = true;
                row.ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("red");
                break;
            }
        }

        if (flag)
            break;
    }

    if (!flag)
        MyGridView.PageIndex = 0;
        //MyGridView_View(sender, e)
}
```

I didn't try this method, but this will give you idea.